# How to prove that Euler's form of quadratic reciprocity if equivalent to the ordinary quadratic reciprocity?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The Euler's form is:

Suppose that $p$ is an odd prime and $a$ is a positive integer not divisible by $p$. If $q$ is a prime with $p\equiv \pm q$ (mod $4a$), then $(\frac{a}{p})=(\frac{a}{q})$.

The ordinary fom is :

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct odd primes. Then
$$(\frac{p}{q})\cdot (\frac{q}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\cdot\frac{q-1}{2}}$$

This is an exercise on Kenneth H. Rosen, Elementary Number Theory. I can't even see a clue of proving this. I'd be grateful if anybody could provide any hint, method or a complete solution.

EDIT: There is a hint given by Rosen, saying that "Consider separately the cases when $p\equiv q$ (mod $4$) and $p\not\equiv q$ (mod $4$)".

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352408/law-of-quadratic-reciprocity-equivalent-statement).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I did see that post. But that is a very different question in my point of view.

Comment: It is not very different. Then $(a/p)=1$ if and only if $(a/q)=1$ in your context, respectively $-1$.